# Using anchor tag to call a view django

Tags: python, html, django, view

project.urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', include('app.urls', namespace = 'app')),
)+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

app.urls

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
# ex: /polls/,
 url(r'^', index.as_view(), name = 'index'),
 url(r'^contact/', ContactMail.as_view(), name = 'contact'),
# url(r'^register/', register.as_view(), name = 'register'),
# url(r'^login/', login_user.as_view(), name = 'login'),
```

)+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()

html

```
<a class="page-scroll" href="{% url 'app:contact' %}">Contact</a>
```

I get the error:

```
Reverse for 'contact' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'$contact/']
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have tried `url(r'^contact/$', ContactMail.as_view(), name = 'contact'),` ? and the same for `url(r'^$', index.as_view(), name = 'index'),`

Answer (score 3):

You've included the app urls via a regex that ends in $, so nothing included will ever match. Don't do that.

```
url(r'^', include('app.urls', namespace = 'app')),
```

Comment: But I want my home page to be www.domainname.com and not www.domainname.com/index/ . What should I do instead? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Including your app urls as

```
url(r'^$', include('app.urls', namespace = 'app')),
```

means that the only url you will get a match for is `www.domainname.com/` because you're telling django that the url must begin with `''`, contain no characters and end in `''`, so in your app's urls the only url that matches that is the `index` view.

If you want you app urls to be served starting at `/`, your urls should be imported at

```
url(r'^', include('app.urls', namespace = 'app')),
```

For example, if you wanted your app urls to start at `/app/`, like `/app/contact/` you would do

```
url(r'^app/', include('app.urls', namespace = 'app')),
```

Check the [django docs on this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs) for more details.